# Can I force a C++ class to be non-abstract?

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance, abstract-class

In my C++ program, I have an abstract class named `Foo` and a class that inherits from it named `Bar` that's not supposed to be abstract. But I often add pure virtual methods to `Foo` and forget to override them in `Bar`, which makes `Bar` also an abstract class. So I often get code like this:

```
class Foo {
public:
    virtual void someMethod() = 0;
    //Other stuff
};

class Bar: public Foo {
    //Other stuff, but I forgot to override someMethod
};

int main(){
    Bar myVariable;    //Error here saying that Bar is abstract
    return 0;
}
```

Of course, this code doesn't compile, but it puts the error at the line `Bar myVariable`, saying that I can't instantiate an abstract class (since I forgot to override `someMethod`, `Bar` is abstract). But I think it would be more helpful if the compiler told me which method I forgot to override, since I have a lot of other things in both `Foo` and `Bar` and so to find what method I forgot to override, I would have to go through each pure virtual method in `Foo` and make sure it's overridden in `Bar`, which takes a lot of time.

So I would like to know if I can tell the compiler that `Bar` isn't supposed to be abstract, so that instead of putting the compiler error at the line where I declare a variable of type `Bar` saying that `Bar` is abstract (which isn't very helpful), it puts the compiler error at the declaration of `Bar` saying something like "You forgot to override `someMethod`". Something like this:

```
nonabstract class Bar: public Foo { //Error here, Bar isn't supposed to be abstract but I didn't override someMethod
    //Some stuff
};
```

I did some research and found the [`final`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final) keyword, which applied to a class does so that the class can't be inherited. I tried marking `Bar` as `final`, thinking that there is no point in having an abstract class that can't be inherited, but in XCode all I got was a warning saying "Abstract class is marked 'final'" (but it still didn't tell me what method I forgot to override), and in Visual Studio it didn't change anything, it didn't even produce a warning. And even if it worked it wouldn't be perfect since I have nothing against having classes that inherit from `Bar`, I just don't want `Bar` to be abstract.

Is there a way I can tell the compiler that `Bar` isn't supposed to be abstract, so that it gives me an error when I forget to override a pure virtual method and tells me what method I forgot to override?

Comment: Which compiler are you using? Because it works [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/776815ade5f45de9)

Comment: *"it would be more helpful if the compiler told me which method I forgot to override"* - That's a quality of implementation issue. The language already specifies the compiler should stop and say something (without any additional specifiers or attributes) when an abstract class is instantiated. So complain to the vendor.

Comment: gcc does tell you which method you forgot; maybe you could use a better compiler

Comment: Classic XY problem. You need better diagnostic tools, not to change your code in weird ways.

Comment: Not a complete answer... (and I wish I had a nice compiler flag for you) but it seems like you could use ack-grep to list all pure virtual functions from you Foo header, and in a shell script, iterate those method names looking for each in your Bar header.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In some IDEs, notably Visual Studio, the "Errors" window only shows you the first line of each error. If you look at the compiler output, it'll show you additional information, if available; in this situation, that information would include what members were missing (and you can double-click on the line of output to go to the associated line of code). I'm not aware of any recent compiler which doesn't tell you which abstract functions were unimplemented.

Comment: That is one reason why I for the most part ignore the Errors tab and instead look at the compiler output in the Output tab.

Comment: This is true.
This is the complete error generated by the compiler:
main.cpp(25): error C2259: 'Bar': cannot instantiate abstract class
main.cpp(25): note: due to following members:
main.cpp(25): note: 'void Foo::someMethod(void)': is abstract
main.cpp(12): note: see declaration of 'Foo::someMethod'

Answer (score 7):

Starting with C++17 you can use `static_assert` to ensure that a certain class is not abstract with [`std::is_abstract<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_abstract):

```
static_assert(!std::is_abstract<Bar>(), "Bar must be non-abstract.");
```

This does not tell you which functions you forgot to override, but it lets you break the compile even in cases when `Bar` is not used. This could help in situations when `Bar` is part of a library that is compiled separately from the code that is using it.

Comment: But how does that help? If I read the question correctly, OP wants to be told which funcitons they forgot to override.

Comment: @juanchopanza " I would like to know if I can tell the compiler that Bar isn't supposed to be abstract"

Comment: I'd suggest you to tell in the answer where to put the static assert. I supposed it's directly after the declaration of `Bar`?

Comment: At the end of the question : *"Is there a way I can tell the compiler that Bar isn't supposed to be abstract, so that it gives me an error when I forget to override a pure virtual method **and tells me what method I forgot to override?**"*

Comment: @dasblinkenlight The compiler already tells them that when they instantiate, but I see knowing at the point of class definition is a marginal gain.

Comment: @juanchopanza: It helps in that the compiler will give an error even if `Bar` has not been tried to instantiate. I think that's what OP is actually asking for.

Comment: @StephanLechner The OP specifically said that the code didn't compile, and that what they wanted was to find out which member was missing. This doesn't have anything to do with that request... in fact, I'd expect it to hide that information.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to make sure that `Bar` is not abstract without the need of trying to instantiate it. For that purpose, you could use a `static_assert` with `std::is_abstract`:

```
class Bar: public Foo {
    //Other stuff, but I forgot to override someMethod
};
static_assert(!std::is_abstract<Bar>(), "Bar is ought to be not abstract.");
```

This will give you a compiler error at the `static_assert`; if you implement `someMethod` (either in `Bar` or in `Foo`), the compiler error will disappear.

Comment: @DonaldDuck "Hundreds of methods in both classes..." That in itself is a big problem.

Comment: That's not really helpful if it doesn't tell me what method I forgot to override. I have about 20 methods in both classes, and I want to avoid checking each one of them to see which one I forgot to override.